# Generating raster (spec. GeoTiff) out of mesh file (.ply)?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mashup, rasterization, opendronemap

I created a mesh file using OpenDroneMap program out of 100 geotagged jpgs, and I would like to know how to generate a raster image out of the resultant .ply file?

Has anyone done this?

Meshlab has the option to make a screenshot but it returns very poor quality image. I saw that Agisoft Photoscan has this ability as well, but are there any free software packages that can do this?

Comment: Btw, OpenDroneMap now has the ability for creating raster images

Answer (score 2):

You can use cloudcompare or meshroom software to convert the .ply mesh file to a point cloud (.las or .laz).

Once you have it in point cloud format (with normals computed), use a simple script in R to grid and output raster at desired resolution.

Sample script:

```
#set working directory
setwd("C:/Path/to/files/")
#dependency
library(lidR)
#read point cloud
las <- readLAS('sfm.las')
#manually override return number
las@data$ReturnNumber <- 1
#plot point cloud
plot(las)
```

[image: cloud]

```
#grid cloud from above
chm <- grid_canopy(las, res = 0.05, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0, 1.5)))
plot(chm)
#output raster file
writeRaster(chm, "raster.tif")
```

[image]